# Alias www.example.com to the same example.com on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance and i have setup a domain with route53 and an elastic IP so that my domain is poiting to the same address all the time. However, I have a problem because only https://example.com is working but not https://www.example.com. I know there must be a way to route or to create an alias so that www.example.com redirects me to example.com, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: So rather than serving the same content on www.example.com and example.com, you want to redirect all requests for www.example.com to example.com, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create alias record for what's called naked Domain. You need to set A record to directly the IP address.

Go to Route53,

Create Record Set

- Name: www.example.com
- Type: A - IPv4 address
- Alias: No
- Alias Target: x.x.x.x (<-- your IP address for example.com)

[AWS Documentation » Amazon Route 53 » Developer Guide » Configuring Amazon Route 53 as Your DNS Service » Working with Resource Record Sets » Supported DNS Record Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat)

[Route53にNaked Domainを設定する方法〜ELBを利用しない場合〜(How to configure Naked Domain for Route53 ~ (without ELB))](http://interu.hatenablog.com/entry/2012/12/18/003614)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect requests for `www.example.com` to `example.com`, you could use **[S3 Static Website Hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)**, and the **[Redirect Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html)** option.

In this case, you would create a bucket named `www.example.com`, and in the Properties for the bucket, enable **Static Website Hosting**, then select **Redirect Requests**, and set the **Target Bucket or Domain** to `www.example.com`. Be sure to record the Endpoint URL. For example, if you created your bucket in `us-west-2` the endpoint would be `www.example.com.static-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Next in Route53, Open the zone for `example.com`, and create a Record Set. In the **Name** field, enter `www` (this field should be followed by `example.com`), set the **Type** to `CNAME - Canonical Name` and **Alias** to `No`. Next in the **Value** field, enter in the Endpoint you recorded from the **Static Website Hosting** section above. Again, if the domain was `www.example.com` and hosted in `us-west-2`, this should be `www.example.com.static-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.